# Combining Cash and Stock Charitable Deductions for U.S. Federal Income Tax; and cutoff of total allowed

Tags: united-states, stocks, income-tax, tax-deduction

For my 2022 return, I have:

(a) cash charitable deductions made in 2022;

(b) unused cash charitable deductions from 2021 which I will exhaust on the 2022 return;

(c) unused stock deductions from 2021 -- i.e., Contributions of stock to a charity .

(d) zero stock deductions made in 2022 (and no deductions for stuff).

The total of (a) plus (b) is less than 60% of my AGI.  Both (a) and (b) are each less than 50% of AGI.

**Calculating the allowable stock deduction (ASD) for the 2022 return**:

Is ASD ={(60%xAGI for 2022) minus (a + b)} with the limitation that ASD is no more than 30% of AGI, and the total of cash plus stock is no more than 60% AGI?

Or is there a complication I am ignoring?  OR, is the cutoff for 2022 returns 50%?

Assume all the charities are eligible for deduction, that I have full documentation, and that taking the standard deduction makes no sense in this case.

Comment: What are stock deductions? Do you mean  unused capital losses from sale of stocks (at a loss)?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate the stock deduction is the deduction from income because of the donation of stock to a qualifying charitable institution.  For a stock held long term, the value of the deduction from income is the value of the stock when it is donated.